# How to write "number of cups per user" for short using symbols?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing

I want to insert a text segment in a figure in my conference paper. Like "number of cups per user", can I use

**#cups/user** ?

I think "cups/user" means an average value, right?
What I need is a X-Y plot where X-axis is user ID, Y-axis is the numbers of cups of each user (not an average). It is supposed to look like:
[image]

Comment: What is wrong with cups/user?  The # is implied.  You wouldn't say #g/L or #m/s.  Can you give some reason why you think you need the # in your situation?

Comment: If the x-axis is user id, then a line graph would be totally inappropriate. You are not showing a trend, you are showing a bunch of discrete values. I'd use a bar chart.

Comment: Since *cups* and *user* are not common metrics, I would read "cups/user" as "either cups or user", as in: "I eat the/an apple." Note how in English the "per" is not always expressed through a dash: mph = miles per hour. I would spell out "cups per user", it is only four characters longer, but avoids any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would just be "cups" on the y axis of the histogram you are describing. (Though you could not explicitly show the numbered axis, put the number on the histogram bars, and title it "Cups" or "Cups Consumed" or "Cups per Year" as appropriate.